# android - Invalid bitmap movement

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I have a problem with moving a bitmap.
The bitmap is larger than the screen.
Code xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/lay_mapa"
    android:clipChildren="false" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/iv_mapa_swiata"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/mapa_swiata"
                android:scaleType="center"
                android:padding="0dp"
                android:paddingBottom="0dp"
                android:paddingLeft="0dp"
                android:paddingRight="0dp"
                android:paddingTop="0dp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Code in java file:

```
    int xCoOrdinate;
int yCoOrdinate;
ImageView mapa_swiata;
```

On onCreate:

```
 mapa_swiata.setOnTouchListener(this);
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

        switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

                xCoOrdinate = (int) (v.getX() - event.getRawX());
                yCoOrdinate = (int) (v.getY() - event.getRawY());

                break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

                v.animate().x(event.getRawX() + xCoOrdinate).y(event.getRawY() + yCoOrdinate).setDuration(0).start();
                break;
        }

        return true;

        }
```

The picture moves in a rather unpredictable way. This is illustrated by the following movie:
https://youtu.be/BJyQjNmj-J4

Answer (score 0):

From experience, dealing with these kinds of issues is a great pain when doing a custom view. I would recommend using a ready-made library like:
https://github.com/chrisbanes/PhotoView

They've solved most of the problems you are gonna come across already.

However, coming back to the code. You are returning true for all the events. This can potentially leave the view in a strange state, especially with the `ACTION_UP` events marked as consumed.

Something like this may work:

```
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
  switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
      xCoOrdinate = (int) (v.getX() - event.getRawX());
      yCoOrdinate = (int) (v.getY() - event.getRawY());
      return true;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
      v.animate().x(event.getRawX() + xCoOrdinate).y(event.getRawY() + yCoOrdinate).setDuration(0).start();
      return true;
    default:
      return false;
  }
}
```

**Update:**

Ok, here are some other thoughts. Lose the animation. Not sure if it is what's happening. You can set the translation of the view using: `setTranslationX()` and `setTranslationY()` and the events from the touch sensor should be enough to make it feel smooth.

Try using a `FrameLayout` as the parent. There is no need here to use `RelativeLayout`.

Also, I would recommend leaving the coordinate values as floats since they are always needed on that type. Saves having to change number precision.

Comment: Changed. Unfortunately, the behavior is the same.

Comment: Do you (or anyone) know any made library who scroll and zoom not  image but layoyts (in this layout will be more clickabke elements).

Comment: The last thing I can think to suggest is to follow this with https://developer.android.com/training/gestures/scale.html along with translation properties of the view